# Java8 and Aspectj plugin are not compatible?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aspectj, java-8

I'm using eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 with STS, Maven and other Web development tools. Today i thinked about trying some lambdas with Java 8, so I installed JDK1.8 and Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2). It was working but when I opened project i was working with I got bunch build errors in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException

It looked like AspectJ plugin was uninstalled, so I installed it again:
AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT) including the AspectJ compiler.
AspectJ compiler for Eclipse

After rebuiling, project works again but I cant use lambdas. In preferences > Compiler compliance level there isn't Java 1.8. It was there before installing AspectJ stuff.

What can I do to make this work together?

Answer (score 5):

You can install the most recent development version of AspectJ plug-in for Kepler, which supports Java 8 at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/43/dev/update

Then re-install the JDT update at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/